# Send data to multiple PHP using post

Tags: php, html, mysql

Actually i am learning php and coded a code simulator in which i want to allow the user to store their data on mysql. But my form is alreaty connected to show.php which display the output at the same time i want to allow the user to save their work. For that i need to send the same data to my database script php. Can anyone tell me how could i do that? here is my script:

```
<table><tr><td id="cbox" style="position:absolute; width: 35%; height:100%;z-index: 512;">
    <section id="codepanel">
        <form action="show.php" target="pre-box" method='send'>
            <section id="html-code">    
                <label>HTML</label>
                    <input value="Update" type="submit" style="position: absolute; right: 30px; padding: 5px;"></input>
                <textarea class="lined" type="text" name="html" rows="10" cols="60"></textarea>
            </section>
            <section id="css-code"> 
                <label>CSS</label>
                <textarea class="lined" type="text" name="css" rows="10" cols="60"></textarea>
            </section>
            <section id="js-code">  
                <label>JavaScript</label>
                <textarea class="lined" type="text" name="js" rows="10" cols="60"></textarea>
            </section>
            <section>
                <p id="credit"></p>
            </section>  
        </form>
    </section>
    </td><td id="shwbox" style="position: absolute; width: 100%;height:100%; z-index: 0;">
    <iframe name="pre-box" src='show.php'></iframe>
    </td></tr></table>
```

Here is the code for show.php

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    // User JavaScript
    <?php
        echo $_REQUEST['js'];
     ?>
     </script>
     <style>
     /***  CSS ***/
     <?php
        echo $_REQUEST['css'];
     ?>

     </style>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- User HTML -->
    <?php
        echo $_REQUEST['html'];
     ?>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and even i want this to connect to this send-to-sql.php

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "-";
$password = "-";
$dbname = "-";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO Pens (HTML, CSS, JS)
VALUES ($_REQUEST['HTML'], $_REQUEST['CSS'], $_REQUEST['JS'])";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Your pen is sucessfully saved.";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: As in above i send the data to show.php the same i want to send the data to send-to-sql.php if user clicks on the save button.

Comment: With plain HTML it is impossible to fire simoultaneos Requests. You would need ajax

Comment: you forget method="post" in your form tag

Comment: you are not showing any **script** here .. you have only posted the **mark-up**. PLease post the script too

Comment: yes method is post but how do i send the same data with another button. in simple manner the one button will save the data and another will allow the preview. @saty

Comment: @AbhishekGhosh which script should i share ? :)

Comment: post the code of `show.php`

Comment: here are the scripts @AbhishekGhosh

Comment: okkay so what you want is - once the user types in the code in different sections and posts it - you will display the output and insert them into the DB ?

Comment: yes.. i want the same..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76702/discussion-between-abhishek-ghosh-and-abhishek-bagul).

Comment: don't you validate the coming data ?

Comment: what if the user enters sql commands , like drop table it will delete your table

Comment: I never thinked about that.. :P thanx i will take care now @Wasim Ahmad

Comment: @abhishekbagul : please look at the answer I have posted :)

Comment: @abhishekbagul : I hope it is as per our discussion in the chat ?

Comment: yes it is :) @Abhishek Ghosh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First things first :

**1.** You should validate the input you are getting from the users. As there is markups,css and scripts there will be a lott of : **"** and **'**(single and double quotes.) You need to replace all the single quotes to double quotes and in the INSERT query use double quotes . This will avoid string being terminating in the query code.

**2.** Now I assume you have 3 sections namely :  HTML , CSS and JS. What you could do is send a JSON data of the form `{'html: theHTMLCode, css:theCSSCode, js : theJSCode'}` - something of this sort.Please visit this [link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/json/json_php_example.htm) for understanding the use of JSON arrays in PHP.

**3.** Once you have the JSON array you can access the individual items it the array and post them in the respective sections.

**NOTE:** The task you are trying to achieve is very large and hence can not be put into code for you.I have given you an overview of what you should be doing.

Answer (score 1):

this is wrong in your code read manual [form method](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_method.asp)

```
<form action="show.php" target="pre-box" method='send'>
                                                 ^^^^
```

it should be post or get

```
<form action="show.php" target="pre-box" method='post'>
```